Unexpected RangeError in Three.js
I've been using Three.js to generate 3D objects in my website and I just came across this problem yesterday.
I was gonna generate a PlaneGeometry
with widthSegments = 1100  and   heightSegments = 17500
Now then the points would have been stored in a position array with
length = 3 * widthSegments * heightSegments = 57750000

which is way lower than the imposed 2^32 length limit of arrays.
But when I tried to run it, it threw a RangeError: Invalid array length
What?
Tried testing it on a Three.js playground, and got the same results.
